# python program using tkinter wont run due to a tclError

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn how to make a GUI with `tkinter` the conde is rather basic but I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
  File "/home/josh/Documents/VSC/python/SECOM/mainWindow.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.wind = Tk()
  File "/home/josh/Documents/VSC/python/SECOM/mainWindow.py", line 12, in <module>
    MW = mainWindow()
```

When I google such error there is only answer for raspberry pi or remote servers and stuff. Im just using ubuntu(20.04) and have a conda (4.8.3) venv with python (3.8). I'm also using VSC and have the venv as interpreter in VSC. HELP :c

`MainWindow.py`

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "SECOM"
        self.wind = Tk()
        self.wind.title(self.title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MW = mainWindow()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: it is not common to have the `Tk()` call inside the constructor of a window, it is better to be a parameter `parent`

Comment: That's good to know I enjoy writting clean code. I tried it both ways but I still get the same error.

Comment: As the error said, you need to set the system environment variable `DISPLAY`.

Comment: Is that for the venv or for my OS? could you give me some key words to change such variable?

Comment: Try opening a terminal and execute `echo $DISPLAY` and see whether something is shown.  If not, execute `export DISPLAY=:0` (`:0` is used in normal case, but it really depends on how your system create the X11 display).  Then try to execute your script in that terminal manually, i.e try executing `python /path/to/your/script`.  If it works, then it is configuration issue in your VSC terminal settings.

Comment: the error is gone. Thx I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking a lot about `windows` in your code, but not much of anything is actually a `window`. Some of it is nothing, at all. Try This.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        #PUT YOUR APP HERE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.title("SECOM")
    root.mainloop()
```

Here are the problems with your script

```
from tkinter import ttk
#importing like this pollutes your namespace
from tkinter import *

class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        #there is no reason to store a reference to the title
        self.title = "SECOM"
        #why are you burying your root in a class property
        self.wind = Tk()
        #this is why you don't need a reference to title
        self.wind.title(self.title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #sure
    MW = mainWindow()
    #window? window where? You buried this in MW.wind
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thx man, This will probably make my life easier later on when writting more conde. Sadly the error remains.